# JAX-RS UriBuilder#buildFromMap not adding query parameters

Tags: java, jax-rs

Problem: `buildFromMap` is not adding query parameters

I'm using JAX-RS API

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>jakarta.ws.rs</groupId>
  <artifactId>jakarta.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
  <version>2.1.6</version>
</dependency>
```

This is my method to build URIs with query parameters

```
    protected URI buildUri(final String uriString, final Map<String, Object> queryParameters) {
        return UriBuilder.fromUri(uriString).buildFromMap(queryParameters);
    }
```

It doesn't add the parameters. I would expect this to pass:

```
        @Test
        public void testBuildUriWithQueryParameters() {
            final var endpoint = "https://www.example.com/test";
            final var queryParameters = Map.<String, Object>of(
                    "field1", "value1",
                    "field2", 2
            );
            final var expected = endpoint + "?field1=value1&field2=2";
            final var actual = httpService.buildUri(endpoint, queryParameters);
            Assertions.assertEquals(expected, actual.toString());
        }
```

But the test fails:

```
org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: 
Expected :https://www.example.com/test?field1=value1&field2=2
Actual   :https://www.example.com/test
```

This implementation passes:

```
    protected URI buildUri(final String uriString, final Map<String, Object> queryParameters) {
        final var uriBuilder = UriBuilder.fromUri(uriString);
        for (final var queryParameter : queryParameters.entrySet()) {
            uriBuilder.queryParam(queryParameter.getKey(), queryParameter.getValue());
        }
        return uriBuilder.build();
    }
```

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/UriBuilder.html#queryParam-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/UriBuilder.html#buildFromMap-java.util.Map- (It's used for _templates_)